# Aspas dentro de aspas (html, php)

Tags: php, html

Tenho um código html e gostaria de colocar na tag  que está dentro do evento onclick de um botão, o endereço que ela deve ir após o click em "SIM", porém acho que estou errando na hora de colocar as aspas. Ao invés dele criar o botão com a notificação correta, é isso que está acontecendo com o botão.

[image: botão fica assim]

Como corrigir para que redirecione dentro deste onclick? Segue código html abaixo.

```html
                                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn" id="excluir" onclick="return toastr.warning('Deseja realmente excluir o produto <?= $value['nome_ProdutosEmpresa'];?>?<br><br><a href="<?= base_url('produtos/atualizar/' . $value['id']) ;?>">SIM</a>')">
   <i class="icon-times" style="width: 12px; text-align: center"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Pergunta besta: por que colocar tudo isso direto no `onclick` do elemento ao invés de definir uma função no JS e apenas executá-la no clique?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda... se estou perguntando dessa maneira é pq quero entender o que estou errando, sei que posso usar da maneira que você comentou, mas minha pergunta não foi essa, abraços

Answer (score 0):

Na hora de definir o href, falta um ponto após o $value['id'], consigo notar inicialmente apenas esse erro.

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger btn" id="excluir" onclick="return toastr.warning('Deseja realmente excluir o produto <?= $value['nome_ProdutosEmpresa'];?>?<br><br><a href="<?= base_url('produtos/atualizar/' . $value['id'] .'') ;?>">SIM</a>')">
 <i class="icon-times" style="width: 12px; text-align: center"></i>
</button>
```